# Can the freezing point of Nitrogen be reduced?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phase-diagram, freezing, cryogenics

There was an interesting Q/A about mixing helium and nitrogen. Is there anything that can be added to liquid nitrogen to reduce it's freezing point to below 63 kelvin?

Comment: High temperature superconductors can deal with higher magnetic fields at colder temperatures. Liquid Hydrogen is an option, but the gas that bubbles off can be very dangerous. Liquid Helium is very expensive and colder than needed.

Answer (score 1):

Low temperature phase diagrams are reasonably abundant in the literature. For simplicity I considered an oxygen-nitrogen mixture which, at the right proportions, is basically air.

[C.S. Barrett et al.](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1669500) in the Journal of Chemical Physics published just such a paper in 1967. Figure 1 shows the phase diagram they determined. Adding oxygen to nitrogen lowers the freezing point, with a eutectic at about 50K at perhaps 22 at.% nitrogen. However, the ~20 at.% oxygen in air looks to drop the freezing point of nitrogen by some 7K or so.

[image]